# Javadoc does not recognize doctitle option/flag

Tags: javadoc

I am running javadoc with my doclet through gradle, and when I am running my javadoc/doclet task, I am receiving the next error:

```
error - invalid flag: -doctitle
```

And after that, the next usage table

```
usage: javadoc [options] [packagenames] [sourcefiles] [@files]
-overview <file>          Read overview documentation from HTML file
-public                   Show only public classes and members
-protected                Show protected/public classes and members (default)
-package                  Show package/protected/public classes and members
-private                  Show all classes and members
-help                     Display command line options and exit
-doclet <class>           Generate output via alternate doclet
-docletpath <path>        Specify where to find doclet class files
-sourcepath <pathlist>    Specify where to find source files
-classpath <pathlist>     Specify where to find user class files
-exclude <pkglist>        Specify a list of packages to exclude
-subpackages <subpkglist> Specify subpackages to recursively load
-breakiterator            Compute 1st sentence with BreakIterator
-bootclasspath <pathlist> Override location of class files loaded
                          by the bootstrap class loader
-source <release>         Provide source compatibility with specified release
-extdirs <dirlist>        Override location of installed extensions
-verbose                  Output messages about what Javadoc is doing
-locale <name>            Locale to be used, e.g. en_US or en_US_WIN
-encoding <name>          Source file encoding name
-quiet                    Do not display status messages
-J<flag>                  Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system
```

Does anyone have an idea from why Javadoc is not accepting that flag? In theory, I am running the javadoc from tools.jar from jdk1.6. I thought it was something that javadoc would always accept that doctitle option. Thank you for your time!

**EDIT**: That doctitle option is part of the Standard Doclet, so it looks like I am not being able to access the Standard Doclet options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDITED:

Got it!
The problem was in the Doclet itself. I was not extending the Standard Doclet ("public class MyDoclet extends Standard {"), so the flags from the Standard Doclet were not available (and doctitle is part of the flags of the Standard Doclet).

Thanks to Paulo for making me "re-think" my answer :-)

Comment: I don't think importing more classes will help. In your compiled doclet class only the types actually used will be mentioned, no other ones, imported or not. Your doclet has to accept (and interpret) the options given, and the doctitle option might not make sense for every doclet, thus it is not a default option.

Comment: Sorry, you are more than right. I was not cleaning before compiling, so I had a lot of things mixed there. The difference is the "extends Standard", in which that doctitle option is included. I will edit the answer then. Thank you very much for your comment!

Answer (score 2):

You can set the task local variable 'title' to empty on the javadoc task

```
task javadocTask(type: Javadoc) {
    title = ""
    //Other items like source and options
}
```

Or alternatively

```
javadocTask.title = ""
```

**Why**

Gradle sets the local variable 'title' in the javadoc task that is then used to populate the -doctitle and -windowtitle arguments.  If it is empty, they will not populate the fields and you can avoid this problem.

Interestingly, title seems to be populated by the java plugin, so if you are running javadoc from a project that does not have java (say as an aggregator project) you will not run into this problem, but if you move the javadoc generation into a java project you will.

Note: `title = ""` and `title = null` both work on the newest version of gradle.  This is likely because gradle knows both `""` and `null` are empty. However, on older versions of gradle, there are reports of using `null`  not working, but an empty string did.

Comment: title = null doesn't seem to work but title = "" does.

Comment: @IanG.Clifton Interesting, both the `title = ""` and `title = null` work for me, but not having it fails. What version of Gradle are you on? Maybe the code changed to do a different version of String.isEmpty() or something ;)

Comment: Strangely, the new project is pointing back to Gradle 1.6 instead of a newer version; I didn't think to check that when I was running into other issues, thanks!

Comment: Since apparently the the key is that title is empty, not null, I updated the answer.